# Flutter WebView works on emulator but not on device

Tags: android, flutter, android-webview

Although I do not know which code of file I should write here, here are the codes :

from the dart file :

```
Container(
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.7,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.9,

                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
                        child:
                        Expanded(
                          child:WebView(
                            initialUrl: url,   // url is String input
                            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                          ),

                        ),
```

from app/src/AndroidManifest.xml :

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:label="colosseum_v2"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
```

from build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.colosseum_v2"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}
```

I am testing this in an android emulator, pixel4, and an android device galaxy fold2.

Since all other parts except webView work, so I do not reason what I missed.

WebView works well on an emulator but only shows a gray screen on my device.

Please tell me what I should do.